# How to skip the blank page in a Pivottable in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The Source Data Range of my PivotTable is longer that my existing data, because of the future addition. For this reaon, in the PivotTable filter, I have a PivotItem called "Blank".

The below code each time changes the PivotItem and then print it, then the next item and so on.

**Problem:** It prints also the "Blank" PivotItem, which has no information. That's why for counting pages I added "-1" to the line `pivF.PivotItems.Count - 1`

**Question:** Can anyone help me to modify the below code to skip that blank page (Or can anyone tell me how can I get rid of that blank PivotItem).

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
 .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
 .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With

Dim pivF As PivotField, pivI As PivotItem, i As Integer
Set pivF = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Leistungsnachweise").PivotFields("Tour")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i = 0
For Each pivI In pivF.PivotItems
        pivF.CurrentPage = pivI.Name
        i = i + 1
        Range("M2").Value = "Seite " & i & " von " & pivF.PivotItems.Count - 1
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut
Next pivI

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Leistungsnachweise").PivotFields("Tour").CurrentPage = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Dynamically determine the range of populated cells from the actual datasource, and then change the datasource on the pivot table to match.

Say, for example, that the `activeRange` you determined through VBA to be Sheet1!A1:M2555:

```
pivF.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
     SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=activeRange)
```

2. Better option, if you can, change your source data to a table (aka ListObject) and then make the ListObject the source of your data rather than a standard range.  ListObjects are better at dynamically sizing when content is altered.  This may preclude the need to extend your range to include blank rows to begin with.

Example:

```
Dim tab as ListObject
Set tab = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

pivF.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
     SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=tab)
```

Or, you could just make the table the source at design time

Comment: Thanks Hambone. Formatting the source data as table was the easiest solution.